# Which datatype and methods should I use?

Tags: c#, dictionary, nlp, search-engine, trie

I am trying to write a kind of simple search engine. I have a determined number of main subjects that are associated with specific keywords. The aim is to recognize the main subject from an input partial keyword. I am thinking of using a : `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. I'll have to search in this dictionary and find, e.g., all keywords beginning with a 3 characters `string` and their main subject which is associated.

Is my solution the best one ? And how can I efficiently look through those data without having to check manually every `List`, `string` by `string`.

Let my know if I'am not clear.

Comment: So will you be searching by keywords only or keywords and content? I am asking because **how can I efficiently look through those data without having to check manually every List, string by string** does not fit with looking at keywords only.

Comment: Are you looking for exact key match or starts with?

Comment: No, I'll be searching by partial keywords. So with "starts with" like Sriram said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Trie data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), it is the recommended way of doing starts with search. Here is a [blog post](http://geekyisawesome.blogspot.ae/2010/07/c-trie.html) talking about it. You can find the [source here](https://code.google.com/p/typocalypse/source/browse/#hg/Trie).

Here's how use the above implementation, code from the above article.

```
//Create trie
Trie < string > trie = new Trie < string > ();

//Add some key-value pairs to the trie
trie.Put("James", "112");
trie.Put("Jake", "222");
trie.Put("Fred", "326");

//Search the trie
trie.Matcher.NextMatch('J'); //Prefix thus far: "J"
trie.Matcher.GetPrefixMatches(); //[112, 222]
trie.Matcher.IsExactMatch(); //false
trie.Matcher.NextMatch('a');
trie.Matcher.NextMatch('m'); //Prefix thus far: "Jam"
trie.Matcher.GetPrefixMatches(); //[112]
trie.Matcher.NextMatch('e');
trie.Matcher.NextMatch('s'); //Prefix thus far: "James"
trie.Matcher.IsExactMatch(); //true
trie.Matcher.GetExactMatch(); //112

//Remove a string-value pair
trie.Remove("James");
```