# Fastest collection to use to find all items with string property starting with

Tags: c#, collections

I'm currently using an ICollection to return all items where `location.path.StartsWith(value)`.

The collection itself is kept in a singleton object and is hydrated on instantiation of the object from a sproc call to a Sql database. While the count of items is only around 1300 the collection itself has the potential to be searched often (I can't define often - maybe 100,000 maybe 1 million - it varies).

Given the details above, perhaps more are needed, what would be the most efficient collection type to use to find all items where `path.StartsWith(value)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are looking for a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) which lets you add an item associated with the key, then find all items that have a key starting with your search term

From the page:

> As discussed below, a trie has a number of advantages over binary
>   search trees.[4] A trie can also be used to replace a hash table, over
>   which it has the following advantages:
>
> - Looking up data in a trie is faster in the worst case, O(m) time (where m is the length of a search string), compared to an imperfect
>     hash table. An imperfect hash table can have key collisions. A key
>     collision is the hash function mapping of different keys to the same
>     position in a hash table. The worst-case lookup speed in an imperfect
>     hash table is O(N) time, but far more typically is O(1), with O(m)
>     time spent evaluating the hash.

IIRC, I had looked for some c# code and found [this implementation](https://trienet.codeplex.com/) to work reasonably well

Edit for comment: 
You would need to scan all keys of a dictionary to see if they start with your search string. In a Trie, you ask for the node that matches your search string, and then you are guaranteed that all elements under that node have a key that start with the search string you gave.

[image: From linked Trie article]

Here you can see that search for `te` would need to drill down two nodes inside the Trie, and that you arrive on a node where all descendants start with `te`

Comment: It seems similar to a Dictionary where it would have KeyValuePairs. Could you give a quick example?

Comment: @bflemi3 I've recommended [this implementation](https://code.google.com/p/typocalypse/source/browse/#hg/Trie) in one of my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23910536/2530848). That has a sample. See if that helps.