# Multithreading in C# does not start

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my Windows Form Application I have a method that searches for the text entered in the search box from a SortedDictionary that contains around 150,000 words then adds the result to the list box. In my searchBox_TextChanged event handler I am creating a new thread and start that but does not work at all. In single thread version my application was working but a little bit slow. I want the search to be faster.

```
private void searchAllWords()
{
    if (searchBox.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        var match = allWords.Keys.Where(x => x.StartsWith(searchBox.Text.Trim().ToLower())).ToArray();
        listBoxWords1.Items.AddRange(match);                
    }
}

private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBoxWords1.Items.Clear();
    Thread searchThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart (searchAllWords));
    searchThread.Start();            
}
```

I know that somewhere the thread should be killed but where and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

- You're accessing the UI in a worker thread, which isn't legal.
- You create new threads each time `TextChanged` fires and forgetting about the thread(s) created earlier.
- You're using the wrong data structure.
- Etc

If you use the right tool, then you don't need a thread at all. You should be using [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure for searching items that starts with expected string.

Refer my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23910536/2530848) for C# implementation of the same.

Comment: Although it is not rule to say thanks but I want to say a special thanks. I really did work. As I wanted.
It was a little though for me to implement but I did it.
thanks

Comment: I noticed that my search engine has a problem. The basic idea that I have implemented is: in searchBox_TextChaned event handler I have implemented that the last character will be pass as NextMatch to the Matcher. For example if I type 'compute' till here all words starting with 'compute' are found and then if I type 'r' then 'r' will passed as character for NextMatch and all words starting with 'computer' will be found, but again when I remove 'r' then 'e' is passed as a Character for NextMatch but I want the list of all those words starting with 'compute'. Any hint please?

Comment: @Hadi You can simply run through computer every time instead of doing it character by character, it won't take much time. You may need it, because user can press delete key, backspace, select some characters and delete them and whatever he/ wants. If this doesn't answers your question, please ask new question with the relevant information, you'll get help. Thanks.